# If $f$ has a pole on $z_0$ then $e^f$ has an infinity order pole (unremovable singularity)

Tags: complex-analysis

**Exercise:** If $f$ has a pole on $z_0$ then $e^f$ has an infinity order pole on $z_0$

(when I mean an infinity order pole I mean that the Laurent series of $e^f$ has infinite many terms $a_k$ where $k<0$ equivalence the limit of $e^f$ at $z_0$ doesn't exist, I am sorry I don't know the definition in English)

**My attempt:** I tried to show that indeed the $\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}e^{f(z)} $ does not exist.

Since $f$ has a pole on $z_0$ I assume its order is $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and i get $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{-n}\frac{1 }{(z-z_0)^{n} }$$

then

$$e^{f(z)}=e^{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{-n}\frac{1 }{(z-z_0)^{n} }}$$

$$\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}e^{f(z)}=\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}e^{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{-n}\frac{1 }{(z-z_0)^{n} }}$$

since $\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n\rightarrow 0$ and $\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}\sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{-n}\frac{1 }{(z-z_0)^{n} }\rightarrow \infty $

$$\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim}e^{f(z)}=e^{\infty}$$ and we know $\underset{z\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}e^{z}$ doesn't exist.

**Is my attempt correct ?**

Comment: $|2n\pi i| \to \infty$. Can you say $e^{2n\pi i} \to e^{\infty}$? Your arguments don't work for complex valued functions.

Comment: FYI, the term in English is "essential singularity".

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy which argument do you refer to ? $e^{\infty}$ doesn't exist thought

Comment: The last three lines in your attempt are invalid.

Comment: ok if i say that $f$ has a pole on $z_0$ therefore the limit goes to $\infty$ and $e^f$ has an essential singularity because $e^{\infty} $ don't exist, is that correct? if not how can i prove it ?

Comment: You are confusing us all! "[T]he Laurent series of $e^f$ has infinite many terms $a_k$ where $k<0$ equivalence the limit of $e^f$ at $z_0$ doesn't exist": these are two different concepts. The first defines an _essential_ singularity; the second just defines an ordinary singularity, which may have a pole of finite order. I think you mean _essential_ singularity?

Comment: @TonyK Of course if we allow $\infty$ as the limit then an essential singularity _is_ an isolated singularity where the function has no limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the essential singularity.
To prove that $z_0$ is the essential singularity of $f(z)$, you should prove that neither $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)$ nor $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)}$ exits. In this problem, $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0^{+}}e^{f(z)}=\infty$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0^{-}}e^{f(z)}$ doesn't exit, so both $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}e^{f(z)}$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{e^{f(z)}}$ don't exit, so $z_0$ is the essential singularity of $e^{f(z)}$

Answer (score 0):

I think your attempt is right just adding a little detail.

In fact, we have a lemma that if $z_0$ is a pole of f, then for any $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exist a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty}z_n=z_0$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(z_n)=\infty$ and $|argf(z_n)-\theta|<\epsilon$.

In this question, let $\theta=0$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\epsilon=\frac{\pi}{8}$, according to the lemma above we know that there exists two sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty}Ref(a_n)=+\infty$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}Ref(b_n)=-\infty$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{f(a_n)}=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{f(b_n)}=0$, which prove that $\lim_{z\to z_0}e^{f(z)}$ don't exist.